# Getting timestamp using MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How can I get the current timestamp using a mysql query?

Answer (score 120):

Depends on which kind you're looking for.

The current integer Unix Timestamp (`1350517005`) can be retrieved like so:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

MySQL often displays timestamps as date/time strings.  To get one of those, these are your basic options ([from the MySQL Date & Time reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)):

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
SELECT NOW();
```

Comment: How do I change this? It is set to UTC I want to change it to IST +0530. I have root access to Ubuntu

Comment: That's worth a new question, but the short answer is that you're probably best off either leaving the server at UTC and using [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), or setting the default time zone using one of the [methods in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).

Answer (score 13):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is standard SQL and works on SQL server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. You should try to keep to the standard as much as you can.

Comment: inserting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in a bigint will not store a unix timestamp

Answer (score 7):

```
Select current_timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3):

just use NOW()

Full reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: `now()` return date+time instead of timestamp