# How to Get Today's date and specific time in SQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need help in my SQL. I need to modify this part "19-DECEMBER-2016 11:00" to something like "TODAY 11:00"

The table where i need to get the date and time is in this format "12/19/2016 11:00 AM"

```
SELECT /*+ FULL MERGE */
a.DATETIME start_time,
a.ENODEB,
a.EUTRANCELL,
a.PERIOD AS Period,

FROM
ALU_EUTRAN.ENB_EUCELL_RRC a
and a.datetime = TO_DATE('19-DECEMBER-2016 11:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

I'll appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting timestamp using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411311/getting-timestamp-using-mysql)

Comment: First things first....which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: 1.  You have a trailing `,` before the `FROM`.  2.  You don't have a `WHERE` clause, only an `AND`.  3.  You have both `MySQL` and `SQL Server` tagged (which DBMS are you *actually* using?)

Comment: `a.datetime = NOW()` unless you want timestamp

Comment: I did not put the whole Query in the above info. I am using TOAD to do my queries....and yes I need the time stamp. a.datetime = NOW () + 11:00AM for example. – ReyFernandez 1 hour ago